# What was the social and cultural role of a "country squire" in Victorian/Edwardian England?

Tags: 19th-century, england, social-history

In Agatha Christie's "The Murder of Roger Ackroyd", the following passage appears:

> Ackroyd has always interested me by being a man more impossibly like a country squire than any country squire could really be. He reminds one of the red-faced sportsmen who always appeared early in the first act of an old-fashioned musical comedy, the setting being the village green. They usually sang a song about going up to London. Nowadays we have revues, and the country squire has died out of musical fashion.

Now, presumably for a contemporary reader at the time (the book was published in 1926) this would be a very illuminating description.  However, as a reader from 90 years in the future, I'm completely at a loss.  What was the role of a "country squire", what did they generally do, what were the intended stereotypes that one might be?  What was the style of an "old-fashioned musical comedy" and are there examples with a country squire I could look up?

My websearches for "Country Squire" have mostly things named after the phrase, such as the motorcar from 1950 and plenty of hostelry.

Comment: Since the question was originated from a novel, I'll comment from a novel. In Jane Austen's Pride and Prejudice, Mr. Bennett, the beleaguered Patron of the family of unwed sisters, was a "Country Squire" and even Mr. Darcy would be termed such.

Comment: Originating in the Duchy of Detroit, the [Country Squire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Country_Squire) was a noble carriage designed to carry the lord of the manor and up to eight members of the household about the park and beyond, sometimes, especially in summer, to special remote holdings of the king known as national parks.

Comment: A well to do country landowner, but not possessing any aristocratic title.

Comment: For another fictional treatment, see *the History of Tom Jones* by Henry Fielding. Mr Allworthy and Mr Western are both squires...

Answer (score 10):

The "country squire" referred to by Christie is essentially a parody of a parody. Yes, an English country squire would be a (possibly substantial)  landowner, a Justice of the Peace - ie a local magistrate - but Christie is alluding to the country squire **in contrast to** more sophisticated London socialites. In this manifestation, he would be a bluff, red-faced countryman, more at home in breeches and boots than evening dress, and happier discussing his hunters and foxhounds with his groom and kennel man than drinking tea in his wife's drawing room. He would be utterly lost in London high society, despite his wealth.

(*I have a vague recollection of a relevant  poem, I'll see if I can track it down.*)

Comment: Good summary. One might add that the country squire had wealth and high *social status*, unlike eg the self-made industrialist who might have more wealth but would still have a provincial accent. The industrialist might be out of place d in all high society, but the squire would be out of place specifically in *urban* high society.

Comment: @NeMo The country squire would quite possibly have a provincial accent too.

Comment: Definitely possible. But his dress other cultural markers would show him to be part of the elite - just not the metropolitan elite.

Answer (score 7):

In the 18th and 19th-centuries, a "squire" could also be a designated landowner (possibly of renown) who served as a private legal entity in the local court system. He was an "arm" of the Judge or Magistrate himself.  Source: http://www.bunker8.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/history/36804.htm - “Law, Ideology & the Gallows in 18th & 19th Century England."       I have a G.G. Grandfather who was always called "Squire" Hugh (1801-1870) - who migrated here to Appalachia - who served on the county court as it was just getting established. Some "squires" meted out punishment in trials, some were paid fees.  They were called "harlan" in earlier centuries (see Crooked Talk: 500 Years of the Language of Crime  by Jonathon Greeen - excerpts are available at books.google).

Answer (score 2):

Is this answered by Wikipedia entries for [squire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squire):

> later a leader in an English village or Lord of the Manor might be
>   called a squire, and later key public figures such as justice of the
>   peace or Member of Parliament.

and [lord of the manor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Manor):

> Lord Denning, in *Corpus Christi College Oxford v Gloucestershire
>   County Council* [1983] QB 360, described the manor thus:
>
> “In mediæval times the manor was the nucleus of English rural life. It
>   was an administrative unit of an extensive area of land. The whole of
>   it was owned originally by the lord of the manor. He lived in the big
>   house called the manor house. Attached to it were many acres of
>   grassland and woodlands called the park. These were the “demesne
>   lands” which were for the personal use of the lord of the manor.
>   Dotted all round were the enclosed homes and land occupied by the
>   “tenants of the manor”.

By 1926 I imagine the title-holder would have few or no special powers, but people would have been familiar with the historical feudal origins.

Answer (score 1):

An esquire had a coat of arms, descending from a knight, the eldest heir eligible to be knighted if he had the money to go along with the blood line. The heir to the hall or manor would be a squire. Some manors came with rights, others didn't. 2 relatives of mine sued each other for the right to hire a vicar like in Jane Austen. The estate was over 2,000 acres and had a farm, village, hamlet, hall and a 2nd manor. A will said tenants owed service with their carts and to do the heir's "other pleasures".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure this provides information on the social/cultural role of a squire, nor is it clear that this answer applies to Victorian/Edwardian England

Answer (score -1):

Squires exerted control in many English villages before the 20th century, but their use of such power obviously varied depending upon individuals and circumstances. A squire was typically a landowner with significant influence and authority in the local community. He often owned a substantial amount of land, which provided economic power. They could control tenant farmers, oversee agricultural activities, and have a say in local economic matters. In some cases, the squire had a also role in local justice and law enforcement. They might preside over a manor court and settle disputes among villagers; lastly, the squire played a key role in local governance. They could be involved in parish affairs, serve as a magistrate, and participate in county-level administration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).